# How to compile a matrix with mixed values?

Tags: matrix, compile

Consider some matrix

```
matrix = {{a,,...,b,...},...},
```

where a,b are some strings (like "Name"), ... inside the row corresponds to numbers, and ... are other similar rows.

Example:

```
tabExample = 
 Table[{"Nam2", i^3, i, Sqrt[i], "Nam1", i^0.1}, {i, 1, 100, 1}]
```

How to compile such a matrix?

The obvious problem is that

```
tabCompiled=Compile[{{tab,_Real,2}},tab]
```

does not work, since the elements of tabExample are not all real.

Comment: This is simply not possible. `Compile` can only work with non-ragged arrays whose entries are only of one type, and only the types `Integer`, `Real`, and `Complex` are available.

Comment: Put another way: the speed from being able to compile necessarily sacrifices flexibility. Something about not being able to have your cake and eat it...

Comment: Not sure you can even call `tabExample` a _matrix_ .